# I can't change my Screen Resolution when Intel Graphic Processor is installed

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, intel-graphics

```
OS: Windows XP Professional Service Pack 2
Mother Board : ASROCK H61M-VS R2.0
Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G630 @ 2.70GHz
2.69GHz, 1.70 GB of RAM
```

When I install Intel Graphics Processor Driver/ VGA Driver . My Screen Resolution appear like this :

[image]

And When I Uninstall it it appeared like this :

[image]

I downloaded all of my drivers [in this site](http://www.asrock.cmm/mb/overview.asp?cat=Download&os=XP&Model=H61M-VS%20R2.0)

Help me fix this

Comment: First suggestion to keep this open and get help: spell check and fix the url so we don't need to

Comment: Most likely the wrong driver if you can't change resolution.

Comment: What happens when you try to change your settings to a reasonable value?

Comment: Don't install it?

Comment: @Jikag . When I change the Settings The Screen Get Black for 2 times then nothing change .

Comment: @TomWijsman - I don't think it is wrong because i downloaded it from the Asrock site and Intel site .

Comment: That doesn't tell whether it's the right driver.

Answer (score 0):

According the the [website you linked](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?cat=Download&os=All&Model=H61M-VS%20R2.0), "**To support Intel's 3rd Generation (Ivy Bridge) CPU, corresponding [BIOS](http://download.asrock.com/bios/1155/H61M-VS(2.10)ROM.zip), [drivers](http://download.asrock.com/drivers/Intel/others/ME_Win7-64_Win7_Vista64_Vista_XP64_XP(v8.0.2.1410_1.5M).zip) and [AXTU](http://download.asrock.com/utility/AXTU/AXTU(v0.1.169).zip) update are required.**" [This looks like an Ivy Bridge CPU](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_Dual-Core/TYPE-Pentium%20Dual-Core.html), so I would imagine that you need to install the listed drivers. There is a download link to them next to VGA XP 32-bit or you can click on the links above and follow the instructions in the installers.

Comment: The G630 is Sandy Bridge not Ivy Bridge.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Never-mind then, this isn't that likely to be helpful.